# Why didn't the Babylon 5 telepaths take over the Markab world?

Tags: babylon-5, telepaths, markab

The Telepaths were looking for a world of their own. The Markab homeworld was available after the plague. Seems like an obvious choice. No mention of any other race taking it.

Answer (score 7):

*Sheridan blew up the local gate.*

In S3E01, Sheridan opens a jump point inside a jump gate to blow up a pursuing shadow vessel.  That gate was the Markab one.  This would render that world hard to access for any given refugees (and looters, Sheridan's thought at the time).

Comment: How big a ship did they have? A large ship could have opened it's own jump point. Or some other ship could have done it for them.

Comment: @FlaStorm32 - if it was just Byron's one group, and they had survival skills, that'd work.  To bring in supplies, and future refugees, a one time drop won't cut it

Comment: @FlaStorm32 the gate being gone ought to take its node completely off the network which would make it very difficult to get to.  A top of the line ship might be able to guess where in hyperspace the system was because we just don't know a lot about B5 physics.  But regardless this was a bigger problem than just opening a jump point.